# What to do when an off-topic question is also a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags

Some questions are closed as off-topic, and some users posts question with exactly the same topic of the closed-one.

Since both flags are Ok, what is the best one in this case? off-topic or duplicate?
An alternative solution would be to allow using the same kind of flag several times.

Comment: If a post is off-topic, then it's off-topic even if it has been asked a million times.

Comment: Close the new one and delete the old one.

Comment: @devnull If a post is a duplicate, then it's a duplicate even if it is offtopic.  ;)  Neither state, being offtopic or a duplicate, precludes the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're welcome to choose either close reason, since they both apply.  Neither is wrong.

Just don't forget the downvote as well.

Comment: @user2284570 If you're not done writing your question then *don't submit it*.  That said, I fail to see how your edits change my answer.  When in this situation, feel free to choose either option.  Neither is wrong.

Comment: Sorry... I really wanted to know what was the best flag, because I already knew both are Ok.

Comment: Downvoting?  I don't downvote merely because a Question is a duplicate.  I did see a question recently that got closed by virtue of off-topic, but which could be cleaned up enough to be a duplicate.  If it happens I'll vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Servy : Do you mean you would vote on an already closed question?

Comment: @hardmath When someone is posting a question without doing sufficient research to ensure that their question is both on topic, and not already answered, it *usually* merits a downvote.  Exceptions would be *very* rare.

Comment: @user2284570 Absolutely.