# What would you choose to close an offtopic question which also a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Imagine there is a question which is essentially offtopic, asking for debugging help but even failed to provide an error message. By one of it's issues it's also a duplicate.

For example, [PDO wordpress query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556709/pdo-wordpress-query) is a sure offtopic, as for the code given, it wouldn't execute even past connect, and never get to the query execution, making it impossible to throw a syntax error in SQL - so, one can guess that provided code is not a real one. Which will make possible answer but a guesswork (save for the dupe part).

Given you've got a Mjölnir dupe hammer and an offtopic vote will *never* get to all five, what would you choose?

- Close as a dupe.
- Vote to close as offtopic and add to ever growing closure queue
- Move on. There is already ten. million. crappy. questions - one more won't make any difference.
- Change Stack Overflow rules to let the OP have their nursing forum-like answer legally?

---

**Update**
There is an interesting comment down below, which explained a closevote with some statements.

First, it stated that "an addition to the second option is unnecessary and criticizing". In fact, this addition is obligatory, to make a whole picture for the reader, stating that **two votes aren't the same:**  one  will make the question closed and another won't. *And if someone thinks that a true description does criticize something, they have to blame the original, not the mirror.*

Second, it says that "To move on is not an option". But [what I can observe with my eyes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222625/stack-overflow-efficiency-shown-by-simple-but-vivid-example) is millions of duplicated or offtopic questions that has been left intact. Means "to move on" *is* an option, and a most used one.

Third states that Stack Overflow is not a community-driven website, but some sort of dictatorship, where no changes can be made ever by the will of community, so, one should never even mention them. I don't know if it's true or false, but I only can tell that such a statement is quite disputable as a closure reason.

Comment: Close it as dupe (The dupe for the main error). And maybe add a comment for the other errors. Or if you want you can write a good answer if OP has many different errors and mistakes in his code.

Comment: Did you really have to add the second half of option 2, not to mention option 3 / 4? I feel like this question isn't as much looking for help, as it is written to criticize SO. Heck, as 92k user, you _know_ 3 & 4 aren't an option.

Comment: For that reason, cv'd as _"This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community."_

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do when an off-topic question is also a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253776/what-to-do-when-an-off-topic-question-is-also-a-duplicate)

Comment: ___2:___ The large queue isn't a valid reason not to cv a question that needs to be closed. ___3:___ Those questions are still open because way too many questions don't get closed in time. That doesn't mean they should stay open. Once again, wrong reason not to act. ___4:___ Killing someone is illegal, let's just make it legal. That suggestion is just stupid.  Frankly, the last 2 options are only an option if you couldn't care less about the quality of SO's contents.

Comment: The [proposed duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253776/what-to-do-when-an-off-topic-question-is-also-a-duplicate) does not mention Mjölnir (which _does_ make a difference) and @Cerbrus reason _"I don't like your phrasing of the options"_ is irrelevant a close reason. OP: I catch your sentiment, but you do may want to rephrase your question somewhat; I made an attempt in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: The phrasing isn't the issue. It's what the OP is saying with those suggestions. The last 2 answers suggest one shouldn't care about the quality of SO's contents. "Criticism" like that about SO's functioning can be found in any of the OP's meta posts. It's his MO.

Comment: @Cerbrus "doing nothing" is always an option, especially when the other options don't apply. So mentioning that option doesn't make it invalid for discussion. I know that OP likes to address issues by phrasing them this way; and I'm having a laugh at every topic by them. Generally I agree with the sentiment too; they seem to address issues that I also recognize.

Comment: @CodeCaster: _"Doing nothing"_ for the wrong reason is _never_ an option. OP doesn't address issues, he merely points them out and provides non-answers that are often enough harmful to the site. I'm not saying SO doesn't have it's issues. Just that this is completely the wrong way of going about trying to "solve" them.

Comment: @Cerbrus OP stated those options as possible actions you can take. They are valid actions. You're discussing them now. OP wonders which action is appropriate. How does this question not seek discussion?

Comment: I'd hardly call this a constructive discussion about how the options can be used to improve the site. Suggesting crappy options isn't a start of a discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't like hypothetical discussions like this, as there are plenty of caveats that depend on the actual content of the question. So please, no "But what if" comments on this answer without linking to an actual question and asking what I would do.

But, say you have a question that is off-topic, too broad or unclear, while you can find one issue in it that you recognize as answered before, can you, wielding Mjölnir, dupehammer the question into closure immediately as opposed to casting a single vote that most likely won't get the question closed?

I think you can. It's a poor question anyway, there will be plenty forth-and-back necessary in comments under the question or potential answers to get the actual problem answered, so a waste of effort altogether while OP doesn't *learn* anything, but just gets their code handed to them if anyone is willing to spend enough effort - while that same code is present in a more general question already (being the target duplicate).

By giving OP a link to a question that at least partially solves their problem, while closing their offtopic question, you're helping them and the rest of SO.

Key example being the question [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). You can use that to dupehammer any *"My code throws a NullReferenceException, please advise"* question. When doing so, I generally also comment *"Your variable `x` is `null`, see duplicate for debugging hints and solutions"*.

Answer (score 7):

You close it as a dupe.

- You're then certain it gets closed
- The OP can (hopefully) see that the dupe was closed as off-topic
- The OP can infer that their question is similarly off-topic
- You might still help the OP get an answer to their question

I tried this strategy recently in a situation where I didn't have the dupehammer. It could have been more successful - the OP didn't bother to read the dupe...